# Where does the metadata about downloaded files get stored?

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

An app named **Downloads** is present in the GINGERBREAD version of Android. It lists the files downloaded. Where are these files stored and are there any standard APIs to access the downloaded files?

Comment: This is what you are looking for(I think): [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).

Answer (score 1):

`os.Environment` has a method called `getDownloadCacheDirectory()` 
You can get a list of all the files in this directory as follows:

```
 File downloadFolder = Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory();
 File[] downloadFiles = downloadFolder.listFiles();
```

Documentation from the [Android developers site.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDownloadCacheDirectory%28%29)